# A conformal map from the complex projective line to the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I need some help with the following problem:

Consider the spheres $\mathbb S^3 \subset \mathbb C^2$ and $\mathbb S^2 \subset \mathbb C \times \mathbb R$ and the function $h:\mathbb S^3 \rightarrow \mathbb S^2$ given by:

$$ h(z_1,z_2):=(2z_1 \overline z_2, |z_1|^2-|z_2|^2)$$

prove $h$ induces a conformal map $\eta: \mathbb CP^1 \rightarrow \mathbb S^2$

it is ovbious how to define the map $\eta$. My problem is how do I prove it is a conformal map whithout doing much calculations? I think I shoud work in the sphere whithout using an atlas for the sphere $\mathbb S^3$ but when I calculated the pullback I got extra terms so I must restrict me to the horizontal space but how do I know wich vertor lay in the horizontal space and witch don't?

Answer (score 2):

This is the hopf fibration of $S^3$. When $z_2 \ne 0$ Let $X+iY=\zeta=\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ be the coordinate of $CP^1$, we have $|z_2|^2=1-|z_1|^2=1-|\zeta|^2|z_2|^2$ hence $|z_2|^2=\frac{1}{1+|\zeta|^2}$. The induced map $\eta$ maps $[z_1, z_2]$ to 
$$(2\zeta, |\zeta|^2-1)|z_2|^2=\frac{(2\zeta, |\zeta|^2-1)}{1+|\zeta|^2}$$ $$=(\frac{2X}{1+X^2+Y^2}, \frac{2Y}{1+X^2+Y^2}, \frac{-1+X^2+Y^2}{1+X^2+Y^2})$$, which is nothing but the [Stereographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)